# Continue Loop Through Offset in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have `$arrLevel` from lopping result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ohp_id] => 98
            [parent_ohp_id] => 84
            [organization_id] => 122
            [position_id] => 32
            [level] => 3
            [seat] => 1
            [description] => 
            [start_date] => 2016-07-21
            [end_date] => 
            [title] => Coordinator Of Support Operational and Mainte
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ohp_id] => 84
            [parent_ohp_id] => 
            [organization_id] => 122
            [position_id] => 2
            [level] => 2
            [seat] => 1
            [description] => 
            [start_date] => 2016-07-21
            [end_date] => 
            [title] => Chief
        )
)

etc...
```

One of them has null `parent_ohp_id`, and in my code it gives error `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`. this is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrPosition); $i++) {
            $hasPosition->loadHas($orgId, $arrPosition[$i]);
            $level = search($arr, 'level', $arrLevel[$i]);
            //print_r($level);
           if(isset($level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'])){
               if((int)$level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'] == (int)$level[$i]['ohp_id']){
                   $parentOhp = null;
               }
               else{
                   $parentOhp = $level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'];
               }
           }
           else{
                $parentOhp = null;
           }
etc...
```

Cause that offset, loop process stop and all array after it can't show/can't continue looping. how to fix it and set undefined offset `parent_ohp_id` to `null`? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use empty() instead of isset():

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrPosition); $i++) {
        $hasPosition->loadHas($orgId, $arrPosition[$i]);
        $level = search($arr, 'level', $arrLevel[$i]);
        //print_r($level);
       if(!empty($level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'])){
           if((int)$level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'] == (int)$level[$i]['ohp_id']){
               $parentOhp = null;
           }
           else{
               $parentOhp = $level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'];
           }
       }
       else{
            $parentOhp = null;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few arrays

- `$arrPosition`
- `$arrLevel`
- `$level`

using same key `$i` inside loop. Because `$i` is simple integer iteration then before your loop you can use this code to be sure that all tables has the same integer keys (without possible lacks)

```
$arrPosition = array_values($arrPosition);
$arrLevel = array_values($arrLevel);
$level = array_values($level);
```

I guess that you need all of the element with index `$i` in every mentioned array so you should add this line just after the for loop statement

```
if (array_key_exists($i, $arrPosition) and array_key_exists($i, $arrLevel) and array_key_exists($i, $level)) {
    //do everything you need inside loop
} //this close brace is just before brace closing your for loop
```

This statement in your code

```
if(isset($level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'])){
```

should be replace to

```
if(!empty($level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'])) {
```

According to above you can replace your code with this

```
$arrPosition = array_values($arrPosition);
$arrLevel = array_values($arrLevel);
$level = array_values($level);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrPosition); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($i, $arrPosition) and array_key_exists($i, $arrLevel) 
        $hasPosition->loadHas($orgId, $arrPosition[$i]);
        $level = search($arr, 'level', $arrLevel[$i]);
        //print_r($level);
        if(!empty($level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'])) {
            if((int)$level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'] == (int)$level[$i]['ohp_id']) {
                $parentOhp = null;
            } else {
                $parentOhp = $level[$i]['parent_ohp_id'];
            }
        } else {
            $parentOhp = null;
        }

etc... [remember to close the if statement before closing for loop]
```

Comment: I've improved my answer. If is it now working then please do a var_dump on every mentioned array and post the result in question.